# Call class dynamically by name (string to class name)

Tags: javascript, class, svelte

I'm making a very simple router in Svelte. Pages are imported as components by passing currentHash (ex: `/#Dashboard`):

```
import Dashboard from './Dashboard.svelte';
import About from './About.svelte';
import NotFound from './404.svelte';

let component = currentHash; // 'Dashboard' as string
```

Later, I'm loading the component using the following:

```
<svelte:component this={component} />
```

That doesn't work as this function doesn't take String but the class itself.

The only thing that works is `let component = eval(currentHash);` and it works but I don't want to use `eval`.

Also, tired `component = window[currentHash]`; and that doesn't work either.

How do I convert a String variable to Class call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to know all possible components that could be rendered and implement a mapping yourself

```html
<script>
import Dashboard from './Dashboard.svelte';
import About from './About.svelte';
import NotFound from './404.svelte';

const componentMap = {
  Dashboard,
  About,
  NotFound
}

let component = currentHash;

</script>

<svelte:component this={componentMap[currentHash]} />
```

Comment: Thanks, I was already using an array for the nav. So now I added component to it `pages: [{ hash: 'Dashboard', component: Dashboard}, ... `  It works now but I don't like the redundancy. Is there really now way to convert that hash string to component?